# A set is open in two metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For $(X,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ is two metric space, set $(X=X_1 \times X_2)$
and $d(x,y)=max\{d_1(x_1,y_1),d_2(x_2,y_2)\}$ , $\overline{d}=d_1(x_1,y_1)+d_2(x_2,y_2)$ with $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2)\in X$.
Prove that a set $G$ is open in $(X,d)$ $\Longleftrightarrow $ $G$ is too open in $(X,\overline{d}).$
I try to use definition of open set: $G$ is open if $\forall x\in G: \exists B(x,r)\subset G$.

Other way, i think we can prove two metric is equivalent.( but i can't finish ).
Can you help me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that
$$
  d \le \bar d \le 2d.
$$
Then notice that every ball in one matric contains a ball for the other metric, and vice-versa.